# Serializing Joda DateTime using groovy.json

Tags: json, serialization, groovy, jodatime

I have this simple pojo class Fueling that i want to serialize to JSON using the built in Groovy JSON Library. However my application halts when trying to serialize.

```
class Fueling {
int id;
int mileage;
double amount;
double cost;
DateTime dateTime;
String userId;
```

}

the following tests renders a java.lang.StackOverflowError:

```
@Test
void parseJoda(){
    def fueling = new Fueling(amount: 1.0, cost: 2.3, mileage: 123, dateTime: DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC));
    def jsonF = JsonOutput.toJson(fueling);

}
```

How can i make this serialization work?

EDIT: The JSON data is for persisting and not for display purpuses, so the actual serialization result format is not important just as long as i am able to get it deserialized again

Comment: Based on this link - http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td4750759 - and this link - http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td5711505 - I think you may need to use Jackson or Gson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you don't care about the format, one simple workaround is to use Maps as your Groovy JSON API input/output and then add in a little code to translate your domain objects to and from Maps.

**Serializing**

You can use the Map that is returned by `getProperties` as-is with two modifications: converting the `DateTime` instance to it's `long` millisecond representation and removing the `class` entry (which lead to memory errors for me)

```
def serialize(){
    def fueling = new Fueling(amount: 1.0, cost: 2.3, mileage: 123, dateTime: DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC));
    JsonOutput.toJson(
        fueling.properties.collectEntries { k, v -> 
            [(k): k == 'dateTime' ? v.millis : v] // represent DateTime as milliseconds
        }.findAll { 
            it.key != 'class' // remove the unnecessary 'class' property
        }
    ) 
}
```

**Deserializing**

You can pass the Map that the JsonSlurper spits out directly to your `Fueling` constructor with the slight modification of converting the `dateTime` entry from `long` back to a `DateTime` instance

```
def deserialize() {
    String json = '{"userId":null,"cost":2.3,"id":0,"dateTime":1439839235603,"amount":1.0,"mileage":123}'
    Map props = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
    new Fueling(props.collectEntries { k, v -> 
        [(k): k == 'dateTime' ? new DateTime(v) : v ] // convert back to DateTime
    })
}
```

Of course, there comes a point when your domain object tree is large/complex enough to warrant the use of a more extensible 3rd-party JSON library.